# Is there a way to get a table with parameters of a function?

Tags: java, arrays, parameters

Say I had a function like this

```
public static boolean test(int a, int b)
```

is there some sort of way to access the parameters in some sort of array somewhere? The reason why is i have a function with a lot of parameters but i want to get them all through a for loop so I want to be able to do something like

```
for(int i; i < 3; i++) test.args[1] do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Java supports "varargs" - see [Arbitrary Number of Arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html):

> You can use a construct called varargs to *pass an arbitrary number of values to a method. You use varargs when you don't know how many of a particular type of argument will be passed to the method.* It's a shortcut to creating [and accepting] an array manually ..
>
> To use varargs, you follow the type of the last parameter by an ellipsis (three dots, ...), then a space, and the parameter name. *The method can then be called with any number of that parameter*, including none.

For instance, in this case that might look like like:

```
public static boolean test(int... args) {
   // now args, a variable of type int[], can be accessed
   for(int i; i < args.length; i++) {
       doStuff(args[i]);
   }
}
```

This is *exclusive* of individually named parameters and as such there is no way to enforce the multiplicity in the type system - the above method will accept 0..n integers.

As far as individual parameters: they can *only* be accessed by bound identifier name and there is *no* "table lookup" available at runtime. A collection could be built/used internally, of course:

```
public static boolean test(int a, int b) {
    int args[] = {a, b};
    // yay, now we got an array of argument values and the method
    // must be invoked with exactly 2 arguments
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking can you pass an array as a parameter? If so then the answer is yes. Below I pass an array of doubles as a parameter to a method.

```
public void meth1 (double[] myList){
   for(int i =0; i<myList.length; i++){
      //Process entries here
   }
}
```